# action="somename" in <form not working in Spring MVC annotation

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have been trying to get a spring MVC test application to work. Here is all my spring code.

My JSP 
home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" %>

 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>iBank - Home-version 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to iBank-Dhiren</h1>
<h2 align="center">Your Online Bank Portal</h2>
<p align="center">   
Today is ${today}.<br/>
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/admin.htm">Modified Administration Site-version-1.0 </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>

<p>
    <form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="user">

        <div>
            <form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="firstName"/>
            <form:errors path="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
            <form:input path="password" />
            <form:errors path="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="middleName">Middle name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="middleName" />
            <form:errors path="middleName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="lastName">LastName:</form:label>
            <form:input path="lastName" />
            <form:errors path="lastName" />
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="  OK  "/>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</p>

</html>
```

My UserLoginController

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

    //@RequestMapping()
    public class UserLoginController {

    public UserLoginController(){

    }
        //@RequestMapping(value="/get" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //@ModelAttribute("user")
        public String get(final ModelMap model) {

            User userForm = new User();
      model.addAttribute("userLogin", userForm);
       return "form";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/user.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String post(final User user, final BindingResult result, Model mv) {

           String test=" inside here";

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

The User class

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class User {
/*  @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 20)
    */
private String userId;
    /*@NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 20)
*/
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
//private int userAccessLevel;
/**
 * @return the userId
 */
public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
/**
 * @param userId the userId to set
 */
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
/**
 * @return the firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
/**
 * @param firstName the firstName to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
/**
 * @return the middleName
 */
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
/**
 * @param middleName the middleName to set
 */
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
/**
 * @param lastName the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
/**
 * @return the userAccessLevel
 *
public int getUserAccessLevel() {
    return userAccessLevel;
}
*/
/**
 * @param userAccessLevel the userAccessLevel to set
 *
public void setUserAccessLevel(int userAccessLevel) {
    this.userAccessLevel = userAccessLevel;
}*/

}
```

and these are the context.xml files 
servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

        <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="mytest.apps" />

</beans:beans>
```

Can some one tell me why the home.jsp does not come up

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>appServlet</display-name>
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>  
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>  
<listener>  
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>  
</listener> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

With all these the error when I try to get to the first page of web application I get this error in Tomcat.

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned where no TLDs were found. Skipping JAR scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [console].
Sep 14, 2011 10:02:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
.
.
Sep 14, 2011 10:02:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/AdministrativeApplication] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 25

22:     <form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="user">
23:      
24:         <div>
25:             <form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label>
26:             <form:input path="firstName"/>
27:             <form:errors path="firstName" />
28:         </div>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
```

Please help

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to look at. Can you try to localize the problem.

Comment: This piece of code does not work . I am not able to figure out why  <form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="user">. If I comment out the part in jsp where <form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="firstName"/>
            <form:errors path="firstName" />
 The JSP shows up.

Comment: I finally figured the solution out. Will put the detailed explaination. The catch in my opinion is the signature of the method that needed to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the main issue . Even though I had the BindingResult and Model and attribute, the signature order was not correct. spring would recgnize this as error as per reference link 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html
Example 15.1. Invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet,
    Model model, BindingResult result) { … }

Note, that there is a Model parameter in between Pet and BindingResult. To get this working you have to reorder the parameters as follows:

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet,
    BindingResult result, Model model) { … }
```

I was not having the correct order of signatures which caused me the issue of BindingResult not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a form with a modelAttribute of "user", but putting the modelAttribute in as "userLogin". If you change either one so they are consistent, it should work.

Comment: I have this code in UserLoginController.                                                       public String get(final ModelMap model) {

            User userForm = new User();
      model.addAttribute("userLogin", userForm);
       return "form";
        } how does this have anything to do with invoking the model attribute. Thanks

Comment: Spring is attempting to create your form tags. You've told it there is a model object named user where it can get that data, but the data is not there when it attempts to render the tags. What is there is a model object named userLogin. Your post code is never getting called, because you aren't able to load the first page. If you change this line model.addAttribute("userLogin", userForm); to model.addAttribute("user", userForm); it should work.